# How do you use a Tomcat JNDI JDBC datasource in Spring Boot

Tags: tomcat7, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application and want to deploy as a WAR to Tomcat 7. As part of this I need to keep configuration out of the WAR, so that I can deploy the same war to my stage and production servers and have it pickup the mysql connection via configuration.

To this end I want to configure my Spring Boot app to use a mysql connection configured as a JNDI datasource in the Tomcat instance.

Can spring boot do this and if so how?

Alternatively is this easy to do in Spring 4 without resorting to xml based configuration.

Comment: guessing: can't you use the org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
  JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
  DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/apolloJNDI");
  return dataSource;
}
```

No "java:comp/env/" its needed because JndiDataSourceLookup internaly calls convertJndiName that add this part. In other clases you should set the complete path.

Answer (score 16):

If you're using Spring Boot 1.2 or greater, this got easier. You can just add this to application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/my_database
```

The relevant docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource

Comment: This used to work for me but now I'm getting a `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial`

Comment: cbmeeks, Could you solve the exception?. I have the same problem.

Comment: dustin.schultz, Do you know if Spring Boot works with jndl which are not in localhost. Something like this: spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/192.151.101.179:7002/jdbc/Procesos

Comment: The InitialContext error is really irritating as I removed it using datasource lookup in my configuration but still the integration test fails by checking application.yml when i intend it to use application-test.yml

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I had done.

Add the following to to `Application.java`

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
  JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
  DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/mysqldb");
  return dataSource;
}
```

Then follow the example in https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ to set up the `TransactionManager` and Hibernate specific properties.

Comment: If you're using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` you a shouldn't need to set up a transaction manager (or any hibernate stuff for basic usage).

Comment: When deploying to tomcat, I was getting "'hibernate.dialect' not set". Is there a way to set that without creating a `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` and `setDatabase(Database.ORACLE)` with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: Try "spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect" (or "spring.jpa.hibernate." In general for hibernate native features, as opposed to Spring ones).

Comment: Actually, it's "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/docs/howto.md#configure-jpa-properties)), and spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.*" ("spring.jpa.hibernate.*" is used for some specific properties that are most commonly used).

Comment: Thanks! Guess I should have read the source for `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` too.

Answer (score 0):

A hint for all of you using **Spring Boot with an external Tomcat**. Please ensure your war doesn't contain any tomcat jars. **Multiple versions of same jar** will produce hidden ClassCastException manifested by javax.naming.NamingException.